# How can I test load for a chat app built on node.js and socket.io?

Tags: performance, load-testing, sockets

Here is the link for a simple chat application with room concept which I'm referring to learn how to create socket.io applications - https://github.com/mcantelon/chatrooms .

I need to test how much load this application takes for socket.io.

How can I test how many connections it serves successfully? Is there any tool or method to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at Jmeter or Gatling?  Both free load testing tools with getting started documentation.

Answer (score 4):

[Artillery](https://artillery.io/) is a load-testing tool with **native** Socket.io support out of the box (and is written in Node.js too).

Why is native Socket.io support important? WebSocket is only one of the underlying transport protocols that Socket.io can use *and* Socket.io layers [its own protocol](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol) on top, so while it's *possible* to test a Socket.io server with something like the WebSocket Plugin for JMeter, it certainly won't be as easy to write your tests as when using something that speaks Socket.io "natively", *and* your tests won't be as realistic (for example, you will skip protocol negotiation and will be connecting straight to the WebSocket endpoint exposed by Socket.io).

(Disclosure: I am the lead developer of Artillery.)

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation with Artillery.io in your answer, or it will be deleted as spam. Please edit your answer to note your association with the tool.

Comment: @hassy veldstra - Is it possible to make a "http get call" even before we start the socket.io engine?
My scenario is that I need an Id from the http get call before the engine(in my case it is socket.io)  starts. My problem is that I cannot make that http call after engine starts as it incurs other performance issues which are not acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Socket.IO uses [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol so you need to look for a load testing tool capable of WebSocket testing.

As far as I'm aware there is a [WebSocket Plugin](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) for  [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which can be used to stress your chat application.

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for more details.